# Laravel - Error while seeding model with different date format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have a model with regular timestamps (`created_at`, `updated_at`)

My model has the property `protected $dateFormat = 'U';` in order to store date as Unix timestamps.

The problem happens when I try to seed the table with these values.

In particular, I'm getting this error:

`PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1526321484' for column 'updated_at' at row 1")`

What's wrong with it?

EDIT:

I'm using MySQL 5.6.38.

Comment: Timestamp isn't a valid datetime format, you have couple of choices, either convert your column to store INT(11) instead of datetime or convert the unix timestamp to datetime

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you are not using a valid datetime format to save the data to your database. The `created_at` and `updated_at` fields require a value in datetime format you are currently trying to save this: `1526321484` which is the wrong format. If you really want to save the time like this you should give the `created_at` and the `updated_at` a different data type like an integer, something like this:

```
$table->integer('created_at');
$table->integer('updated_at');
```

If you used this to create the created_at and the updated_at time:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

You have to remove it since it generated those with the datetime format.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. My second question is, will Eloquent keep updating `created_at` and `updated_at` values if they're integers?

Comment: What do you mean with "will Eloquent keep updating the fields", if you create those fields with an integer as a datetype, you could just update your values yourself and put integer values.

Comment: I mean that, whenever you update the model these values get updated as well.

Comment: @FelipePeña yes just update those values whenever to update the model. Pretty simple you think to difficult I think. Whenever you run a store/update method update these values and it should work just fine